# Why does adding x + 1 skip 10?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

Okay so I know this is very basic but I'm confused. When I run this code:

```
int main(){
int arr[10];
for (int x = 1; x < 11; x++){
    arr[x] = x + 1;
    cout<< arr[10];
  }
}
```

The output is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11.

Why does it print 11 and not 10???

Comment: Your program has undefined behaviour because it reads uninitialized data and because it performs out of bounds access of the array. A basic textbook should teach you how arrays work in C++, though.

Comment: Well, you appear to be printing `arr[10]` every time instead of the value you just assigned, and `arr[10]` is out of bounds. Anything could happen. (You also write to `arr[10]` at the end.)

Comment: You're only outputting the 10th item in the array.

Comment: In the final iteration of the loop you are exceeding the array bounds.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen in every iteration, actually

Comment: every time the loop executes he is out of bounds, @nhouser9 nice

Comment: Your output contains commas?  Why not copy and paste the actual output?  There are probably no commas in your output, [as seen by this example](http://ideone.com/iN9k3s)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i just did that for the sake of readability

Comment: @Corpse If you change the output to what it really is, that can skew the answers to your questions.  It also gives doubt if this is the actual code you're running.

Answer (score 0):

You’re printing `arr[10]` every time around the loop. `arr[10]` is out of bounds, so your program has undefined behaviour. Why does the undefined behaviour behave as it does, though? The likely explanation is that your program has been compiled in this instance such that the next value on the stack after `arr[9]` is `x`, the variable you’re incrementing from 1 to 10. Your program therefore assigns to `arr[x]` and happens to print `x` (which is what the out-of-bounds access `arr[10]` reads) for the first nine iterations. On the tenth iteration, it assigns 11 to `arr[10]` and prints that.

Comment: so what do I need to do to have it print 1-10?

Comment: @Corpse: Loop from 0 to 9 (the array’s indexes, `x = 0; x < 10`) instead, and print `arr[x]` instead of `arr[10]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you create an array like this : `int arr[10]`, then, because of 0-based numbering you can access the following elements : `arr[0], arr[1], ... arr[8], arr[9]`. Your program tries to access element `arr[10]` which is out of this range, so this in undefined behavior.